# MySQL: character encoding used by SELECT INTO?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to export some data from a MySQL database, but weird and wonderful things are happening to unicode in that table.

I will focus on one character, the left smartquote: “

When I use `SELECT` from the console, it is printed without issue:

```
mysql> SELECT text FROM posts;
+-------+
| text  |
+-------+
| “foo” |
+-------+
```

This means the data are being sent to my terminal as utf-8[0] (which is correct).

However, when I use `SELECT * FROM posts INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/x.csv' …;`, the output file is *not* correctly encoded:

```
$ cat /tmp/x.csv
â€œfooâ€
```

Specifically, the `“` is encoded with seven (7!) bytes: `\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\x93`.

What encoding is this? Or how could I tell MySQL to use a less unreasonable encoding?

Also, some miscellaneous facts:

- `SELECT @@character_set_database` returns `latin1`
- The `text` column is a `VARCHAR(42)`:

  `mysql> DESCRIBE posts;
  +-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  | Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
  +-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  | text  | varchar(42) | NO   | MUL |         |       |
  +-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+`
- `“` encoded as utf-8 yields `\xe2\x80\x9c`
- `\xe2\x80\x9c` decoded as `latin1` then re-encoded as `utf-8` yields `\xc3\xa2\xc2\x80\xc2\x9c` (6 bytes).
- Another data point: `…` (utf-8: `\xe2\x80\xa6`) is encoded to `\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc2\xa6`

[0]: as smart quotes aren't included in any 8-bit encoding, and my terminal correctly renders utf-8 characters.

Comment: Why use this, rather than a mysqldump?!

Comment: I used `SELECT INTO` because I wanted to filter and join the data a bit before export. I could probably get away without that, though… Because some data would be better than entirely broken data.

Comment: You could clone the database, and make the necessary updates to the clone, to get your desired export.

Comment: That would work… But at this point I think I'm just going to write a little Python script to do the dump for me.

Comment: I wonder why we usually surround the problem, instead of solve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many programs/standards (including MySQL) assume that "latin1" means "cp1252", so the 0x80 byte is interpreted as a Euro symbol, which is where that `\xe2\x82\xac` bit (U+20AC) comes from in the middle.

When I try this, it works properly (but note how I put data in, and the variables set on the db server):

```
mysql> set names utf8; -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html
mysql> create table sq (c varchar(10)) character set utf8;
mysql> show create table sq\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: sq
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `sq` (
  `c` varchar(10) default NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.19 sec)

mysql> insert into sq values (unhex('E2809C'));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select hex(c), c from sq;
+--------+------+
| hex(c) | c    |
+--------+------+
| E2809C | “  |
+--------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from sq into outfile '/tmp/x.csv';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> show variables like "%char%";
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       | 
| character_set_connection | utf8                       | 
| character_set_database   | utf8                       | 
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     | 
| character_set_results    | utf8                       | 
| character_set_server     | latin1                     | 
| character_set_system     | utf8                       | 
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ | 
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And from the shell:

```
/tmp$ hexdump -C x.csv
00000000  e2 80 9c 0a                                       |....|
00000004
```

Hopefully there's a useful tidbit in there…

Comment: Bingo. That's it: `"\xe2\x80\x9c".decode("cp1252").encode("utf-8")` yields `"\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\x93"`. Thanks!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here, but that means that the documentation is also lying when it says "columns are dumped using the binary character set"… okay.jpg :(

Comment: Ok, so I haven't fully figured out what's going on yet, but when I `SET CHARACTER SET utf8`, I start to see similar breakage in my terminal: `SELECT text FROM posts` yields `â€œ` instead of `“` (setting the character set back to latin1 "fixes" that "issue". This is (I assume) because the post text effectively being double-decoded (ie, the utf8 bytes being decoded as cp1252, then encoded again as utf8: `"\xe2\x80\x9c".decode("cp1252").encode("utf-8")` yields “â€œ”)

Comment: (where as, when the connection's character set is "latin1" (ie, cp1252), the bytes are being decoded as cp1252, but then re-encoded as cp1252, yielding the original (utf8) bytes)

Answer (score 26):

Newer versions of MySQL have an option to set the character set in the outfile clause:

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3 
FROM table1 
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/out.txt' 
CHARACTER SET utf8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

Comment: I don't know what "newer versions" are in 2013. For the record: This also worked on an old legacy system of ours, using **MySQL 5.1**

Answer (score 3):

I've found that this works well.

```
SELECT convert(col_name USING latin1) FROM posts INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/x.csv' …;
```

Answer (score 2):

To specifically address your question "What is this?", you have answered it yourself:

> I suspect this is because “Column values are dumped using the binary character set. In effect, there is no character set conversion.” - dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html

That is the way MySQL stores `utf8` encoded data internally. It's a terribly inefficient variation of Unicode storage, apparently using a full three bytes for most characters, and not supporting four byte UTF-8 sequences.

As for how to convert it to real UTF-8 using `INTO OUTFILE`... I don't know. Using other `mysqldump` methods will do it though.

Comment: Ah… mmm… So, out of curiosity, how does MySQL encode unicode data internally?

Comment: I wish I knew. I poked around the documentation when writing this answer, but couldn't come up with anything specific. It's not UCS-2, it's not UTF-8, it's not UTF-16. I just have lingering passive knowledge that MySQL's "UTF-8" storage is not UTF-8 and not very optimized. Might be worth opening a new question for.

Comment: So, it looks like the documentation is lying (or, at least, misleading). @taavi seems to have found the answer — MySQL's “latin1” is actually *cp1252*, so MySQL is decoding the text as cp1252, then encoding it as utf-8. Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

As you can see my MySQL database use `latin1` and system is `utf-8`.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character\_set\_%';
+--------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name            | Value  |
+--------------------------+--------+
| character_set_client     | latin1 |
| character_set_connection | latin1 |
| character_set_database   | latin1 |
| character_set_filesystem | binary |
| character_set_results    | latin1 |
| character_set_server     | latin1 |
| character_set_system     | utf8   |
+--------------------------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Every time I tried to export table I got strange encoded CSV file.
So, I put:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES CP1252");
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=cp1252');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=output.csv');
```

as in my [export script](https://snipt.net/ludojad/-863/).

Then I have pure UTF-8 output.

Answer (score 1):

Try `SET CHARACTER SET <blah>` before your select, `<blah>=utf8` or `latin1` etc...
See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-connection.html

Or `SET NAMES utf8;` might work...

Comment: Nope… Neither of those have any effect on the output file :(

Answer (score 1):

You can execute MySQL queries using the CLI tool (I believe even with an output format so it prints out CSV) and redirect to a file.  Should do charset conversion and still give you access to do joins, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to issue `charset utf8` at the MySQL prompt before running the `SELECT`. This tells the server what to output the results as.

Comment: This does not change the result.

Comment: You get the same results as without it? Or you get a different result but its still not correct.

Comment: And setting `charset latin1` doesn't change the result either.

Comment: I get the identical result. I suspect this is because “Column values are dumped using the binary character set. In effect, there is no character set conversion.” - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html